# PyOpenGL: Rendering... Well... Anything really

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I've been working on a project using python with OpenGL for a while now. I previously posted a similar problem, but I have since done some more research and switched to non-deprecated functions. Following [this tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html) (Translating it to Python versions obviously) I end up with this code:

```
import sys
import OpenGL

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut import *
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import pygame
import Image
import numpy    

class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Splash = True    #There's actually more here, but it's impertinent
    def TexFromPNG(self, filename):
        img = Image.open(filename) # .jpg, .bmp, etc. also work
        img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), 'B')
        texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
        return texture
    def MakeBuffer(self, target, data, size):
        TempBuffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(target, TempBuffer)
        glBufferData(target, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        return TempBuffer
    def ReadFile(self, filename):
        tempfile = open(filename,'r')
        source = tempfile.read()
        temprfile.close()
        return source
    def run(self):
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)

        glutInitWindowSize(256,244)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow("test")
        glutReshapeFunc(self.reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw)
        glutKeyboardFunc(self.keypress)

        self.MainTex = glGenTextures(1)
        self.SplashTex = self.TexFromPNG("Resources/Splash.png")
        MainVertexData = numpy.array([-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1],numpy.float32)
        FullWindowVertices = numpy.array([0,1,2,3],numpy.ushort)
        self.MainVertexData = self.MakeBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,MainVertexData,len(MainVertexData))
        self.FullWindowVertices = self.MakeBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,FullWindowVertices,len(FullWindowVertices))
        self.BaseProgram = compileProgram(compileShader(self.ReadFile("Shaders/Mainv.glsl"),
                                         GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                         compileShader(self.ReadFile("Shaders/Mainf.glsl"),
                                         GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
        glutMainLoop()
    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        glutPostRedisplay()
    def draw(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)        

        glClearDepth(1)
        glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        if self.Splash:
            glUseProgram(self.BaseProgram)
            pos = glGetAttribLocation(self.BaseProgram, "position")
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.SplashTex)
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(self.BaseProgram,"texture"), 0)

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.MainVertexData)
            glVertexAttribPointer(pos,
                                  2,
                                  GL_FLOAT,
                                  GL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  numpy.array([0],numpy.uint8))
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.FullWindowVertices)
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
                           4,
                           GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                           numpy.array([0],numpy.uint8))
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(pos)
        else:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.MainTex)



        glutSwapBuffers()
glutInit(sys.argv)
test = AClass()
test.run()
```

Shaders/Mainv.glsl and Shaders/Mainf.glsl contain:

```
#version 110

attribute vec2 position;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = position * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
```

and:

```
#version 110

uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texcoord);
 }
```

respectively.

This code nets me with a (clear color) GLUT window, which seems to suggest that it's not rendering my triangles for some reason, but I have no idea why that could be, and I can't really find any examples for PyOpenGL that don't use deprecated functions, so I can't see if they did anything different from me that I'm missing.

Comment: If possible, you should reduce your code to a simple test case showing your issue before posting it on SO :) In particular, the code above imports pygame for no reason, relies on a texture file that's not needed to show the problem (even a simple flat shaded triangle would not have worked due to the issues above) and has typos preventing it from running as is ;)

Comment: I will keep that in mind in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get your code working after fixing the following things:

- glBufferData takes the size of the data in bytes, not elements: you need to multiply by 4 for the vertex data (floats) and 2 for the index data (short ints)
- if using VBOs (which you are), the last parameter to glVertexAttribPointer is an offset into the target currently bound to ARRAY_BUFFER; in your case, it should be a null pointer, i.e. None when using pyOpenGL
- glDrawElements behaves the same way: the last parameter is an offset into ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i.e. None in this case

My test image displayed after that, although colors were garbled. I did not attempt to debug that as the options you use to decode your png file might be specific to your data :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same color garbling issue, so apparently my texture making code isn't as good as it could be, but at least it's actually rendering SOMETHING now, fixing the texture creation should be pretty trivial at this point. Thanks a lot.

Edit: How silly of me, I needed to change the output format of the texture to RGBA as well in case anyone is interested in how to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a useful reference for anyone starting out with PyOpenGL and the programmable pipleline, so I've corrected the code according to comments by Bethor and Josiah above, and have also simplified it a bit (embedded the shaders as strings). This code works for me. It assumes that you have **test.png** in the same directory.

```
import sys
import OpenGL

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut import *
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import Image
import numpy    

# vertex shader
strVS = """
attribute vec2 position;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = position * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
"""

# fragment shader
strFS = """
uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texcoord);
}
"""

class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Splash = True    #There's actually more here, but it's impertinent
    def TexFromPNG(self, filename):
        img = Image.open(filename) # .jpg, .bmp, etc. also work
        img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), 'B')
        texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
        return texture
    def MakeBuffer(self, target, data, size):
        TempBuffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(target, TempBuffer)
        glBufferData(target, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        return TempBuffer
    def run(self):
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)

        glutInitWindowSize(256,244)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow("test")
        glutReshapeFunc(self.reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw)

        self.MainTex = glGenTextures(1)
        self.SplashTex = self.TexFromPNG("test.png")
        MainVertexData = numpy.array([-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1],numpy.float32)
        FullWindowVertices = numpy.array([0,1,2,3],numpy.ushort)
        self.MainVertexData = self.MakeBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,MainVertexData,4*len(MainVertexData))
        self.FullWindowVertices = self.MakeBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,FullWindowVertices,2*len(FullWindowVertices))
        self.BaseProgram = compileProgram(compileShader(strVS,
                                                        GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                          compileShader(strFS,
                                                        GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
        glutMainLoop()
    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        glutPostRedisplay()
    def draw(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)        

        glClearDepth(1)
        glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        if self.Splash:
            glUseProgram(self.BaseProgram)
            pos = glGetAttribLocation(self.BaseProgram, "position")
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.SplashTex)
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(self.BaseProgram,"texture"), 0)

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.MainVertexData)
            glVertexAttribPointer(pos,
                                  2,
                                  GL_FLOAT,
                                  GL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  None)
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.FullWindowVertices)
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
                           4,
                           GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                           None)
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(pos)
        else:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.MainTex)

        glutSwapBuffers()

glutInit(sys.argv)
test = AClass()
test.run()
```

Here is the output:

[image]